# The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) when word2vec applied for dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-mllib

I apply Spark's word2vec by using a dataframe. Here is my code:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("LABEL").agg(collect_list("TERM").alias("TERM"))

    val word2Vec = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("TERM")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setMinCount(0)

val model = word2Vec.fit(df2)
    val result = model.transform(df2)

    val synonyms = model.findSynonyms("4", 10)

    //synonyms.foreach(println)

    for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {
      println(s"$synonym $cosineSimilarity")
    }
```

When I use `synonyms.foreach(println)` the code works, however, the returned results are not ordered based on their similarity scores. Instead I have tried the for loop seen at bottom of the code. When applying it the following error has been thrown:

```
Error:(52, 40) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
    for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {
                                       ^
```

From other similar stackoverflow questions and the error, it seems the exact types of arguments are needed. In the for loop `synonyms` is a dataframe and the returned values have types String and Double, respectively. So all my trials have failed. How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `findSynonyms` is a non-materialized Spark-internal `DataFrame`.  You can not simply iterate on the result.

```
  def findSynonyms(word: Vector, num: Int): DataFrame = {
    ..
    sc.parallelize(wordVectors.findSynonyms(word, num)).toDF("word", "similarity")
  }
```

Note the reason `foreach` worked is that is a *materialization* method clearly defined on `DataFrame`'s